# не выполняется $this в статическом методе php

Tags: php

Есть класс

```
class Content
{
    protected $contents; // Экземпляр класса

    private $db;
    private $db_host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "test";
    private $db_user = "test";
    private $db_pass = "test";

    protected function __construct() {
        $this->contents = array();
        $this->connectDb($this->db_name, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_host);
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->db = null;
    }

    public static function getContent($ids) {
        $content = new Content();
        $query = "select t2.content from role_content as t1 join content as t2 on t1.content_id = t2.id where t1.id = :id";
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute(
            array(
                ":id" => $ids
            )
        );

        while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $content->contents[$result["content"]];
        }
        return $content;
    }

    // Устанавливаем соединение с базой
    public function connectdb($db_name, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_host = "localhost")
    {
        try {
            $this->db = new \pdo("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
        } catch (\pdoexception $e) {
            echo "database error: " . $e->getmessage();
            die();
        }
        $this->db->query('set names utf8');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

При обращении к методу getContent() из другого класса в логах вижу ошибку фатальную ошибку php `Using $this when not in object context` в 31 строке `$sth = $this->db->prepare($query);`

Полагаю что при обращении к статическому объекту это происходит, но как это можно исправить?

Comment: А вы вообще  знаете чем зачем статический метод нужен?

Answer (score 1):

Из **[документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php)** (и основ по языку программирования в целом):

> Объявление свойств и методов класса статическими позволяет обращаться
> к ним без создания экземпляра класса. К ним также можно получить
> доступ статически в созданном экземпляре объекта класса.

> Так как статические методы вызываются без создания экземпляра класса,
> то псевдопеременная **$this** недоступна внутри статических методов.

Думаю это более, чем исчерпывающий ответ

---

Как исправить. Почему бы не сделать `getContent` не статическим? Либо придётся обращаться странным образом вот так: `$content->db->...`

---

А ещё надо бы вынести всю работу с подключением и методами БД - в отдельный класс и в текущем как минимум просто брать от него коннект и юзать методы....в лучшем случае в виде dependenсy прокидывать в конструктор, которыая автоматом где-либо это делает (но это уже ещё бОльший уровень продвинутости %))